# Can Hideo rejoin Diamond Dogs?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain, metal-gear-solid-5-ground-zeroes

I haven't tested it as I want to be careful beforehand, but in Metal Gear Solid V: The Phantom Pain, what would happen if you put Hideo Kojima in the Combat Unit position, used him in the field, and he died? Could I just reupload my MGS V: GZ save and will he come back?

Comment: I don't think you can send Kojima on a mission in the first place, so he won't die anyway.

Comment: @Nolonar That is unfortunate. Well, this question is pointless... but MODS!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because that is isn't possible to play as Hideo Kojima without mods in MGS V: TPP.

Comment: @mugen2099 It not being possible without mods in no way, shape, or form makes this question off-topic.

Comment: I think the answer is "No", though, since he'd be a direct contract (i.e., can't change) with the intel team, yeah?

Answer (score 4):

Kojima can be put into the Combat unit but cannot be deployed.

He will not show up in the selectable character list, so the only bearing he has  in the unit will be his rank going towards the overall level of the unit.